# What is the problem with structs having just arrays as its members?

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: The struct has all its members omitted, therefore the getter cannot return any values.
> --> Test.sol:11:5

for the following smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

struct A
{
    uint[] values;
}

contract Test
{
    A public a;
}
```

The error is no longer issued if I add at least 1 non-array member of either a primitive or a custom (user-defined) type to the struct A.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters:%7E:text=data%3B%0A%7D-,It%20generates%20a,-function%20of%20the)

- When set `A public a`, it auto generate a defaut getter for `a`. And follow the docs, nothing is return in that default getter, so it raised the issue. But when you put 1 non-array member in struct, it's possible. This is example

```
struct A
{
    uint[] values;
}

contract Test
{
    A public a;

    // default getter
    function a() public view returns() {}; // error
}
```

---

```
struct A
{
    uint[] values;
    uint256 value2;
}

contract Test
{
    A public a;

    // default getter
    function a() public view returns(uint256 value2) {
       value2 = a.value2;
    }; // success
}
```

- You could try this, let's remove public & declare your own getter.

```
struct A
{
    uint256[] values;
}

contract TestA
{
    A a;

    function set(uint256 _b) external {
        a.values.push(_b);
    }
    function get() external view returns(A memory) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reference to the documentation!

Comment: What I understood from it, is that the part of Solidity that is responsible for automatically generating getters for the public state members of a contract, for some reason, intentionally "omits" mappings and arrays (with the exception of byte arrays).

What I didn't understand, is why it happens like that if it's possible to return a struct containing an array explicitly (what you did in your last code sample)...

Any explanation for the "why"? :)

Comment: In my opinion:
- mapping: can't know which is the key to retrieve value.
- array: it's a default getter, it's a view function. But view functions doesn't mean it's free gas, it's just a simulation of your execution off-chain without sending a tx. Solidity doesn't have hard limit for response data but it has a limitation for gas, So I think it doesn't want your default getter "dead" unexpected => it doesn't auto return array by default getter. As you know, a default getter of an array is: get(uint index), not full of array. So basically => same with mapping because no key to retrieve value